# Using a list to exclude results from wget command download

Tags: linux, wget

Say I have a file called `download.txt`.  In this list is the following:

```
File1.file
File2.file
File3.file
```

Is there a way to use `wget` command to use that list to download all files from a directory except for `File1.file`, `File2.file` and `File3.file`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to ignore files in `wget` based on the file list. It is preferred to use regex (`--reject-regex`) or list on command line (`-R rejlist`), if you can define the files this way.

If you can't, you can convert the list on-the-fly such as:

```
wget -R "$(tr '\n' ','< download.txt)" URL
```